# Windows 7 won't show SATA Hard Drive in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I have clean install of Windows 7 x64 with two SATA hard drives. When I open *My Computer*, I can see only the drive where Windows are installed (and all partitions), but I don't see the other one.

When I go to disk manager, I can see that both drives are detected and the one that I don't see in *My Computer* is also marked as **Primary**, but when I right click, the *Open* and *Browse* are gray.

I also checked drives with *gparted* on live Ubuntu and they both seem to work correctly, the second drive wasn't marked hidden or anything else. Before installing Windows 7, I had Windows XP, where both drives worked properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the drive in disk manager and see if you have the option to map it to a drive letter.

If that doesn't work, can you please take a screenshot and attach it to your original question.

Comment: thx, assigning letter worked

Comment: Cool! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem this is how I fixed it.

Control panel > Administrative Tools > Disk Management - You'll see the disk with an exclamation mark - it is a foreign disk, righ click and select Import Foreign disk.

Answer (score 0):

*Control Panel ⇨ All Control Panel Items ⇨ Administrative Tools ⇨ Computer Management ⇨ Storage ⇨ Disk Management*

You should see it listed and you will then need to make a new volume. This does not in any way address Raid. This is simply how I found it in my system. I have a standard EIDE drive as my OS drive, then added a larger HDD for storage. Being new to Windows 7, this helped, but it missed a few parts I had to find.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that windows for some reason unassigned my drive's path letter...
repaired this by doing:

Control panel> All Control Panel Items > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management -> Change letter and path to unit (not sure if this is really what it says because i use Spanish windows[cambiar letra y rutas de acceso a la unidad]).. fixed it!