# Windows 7 won't show SATA Hard Drive in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I know this is a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/64749/windows-7-wont-show-sata-hard-drive-in-my-computer), but please don't delete it. I am stuck and do not have the option to assign a drive letter. When I right click on the drive that option is grayed out.
[image]

Comment: What shows up when you right click on it, is any option not greyed out?

Comment: And take a screenshot using print screen and paste into a png using paint.

Comment: I added the screenshot. I also unchecked the setting to hide hidden drives, etc under FOLDER OPTIONS.

Comment: The drive appears to already have two partitions on it. What file system are they currently formatted to? Windows will only be able to deal with FAT32 and NTFS.

Comment: it is NTFS formatted

Comment: Does it contain data that you need to retain? If not, I see the Delete volume option is available in your contextual menu...

Comment: No, It is backed up. The small partition is Linux swap space. Do you recommend deleting both?

Comment: @Jay_Booney, I deleted and reformatted the drive. It now shows up. THANK YOU! This has taken me days to figure out!

Comment: Glad to be of help.