# Windows 7 sees second hard drive but won't assign letter

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

This is not a duplicate of [Windows 7 won't show SATA Hard Drive in My Computer](https://superuser.com/questions/64749/windows-7-wont-show-sata-hard-drive-in-my-computer)

I connected a second 1TB [WD SATA hard drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088PUEPK) to my machine. The hard drive still has remnants of an Ubuntu installation which was probably had ext3 or ext4 file system. The 1TB drive is shown below as the first and second entries. The drive is otherwise inaccessible. When right-clicking, the option to assign a drive letter is disabled. The only option available is to Delete Volume. How do you make this second drive accessible from Windows? Does the volume need to be deleted?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search on Google shows Windows 7 cannot read ext3/4 formats.  There are supposedly programs you can download and run to install some sort of driver or shim so the partition can be accessed, but several of them come with the caveat that if you use them improperly, it may damage the partition and render it unreadable.

Do you need to access anything on this drive?  If not, go ahead, delete the partition and repartition it under Windows.  If you do need info of this partition, do a search for whatever program/driver you feel most comfortable with.  I won't recommend any due to the possibility of data loss.

Comment: @T.Webster: If you need some data from the `ext3/4` partitions, I would rather go the other way round. Boot a Linux Live CD (e.g. http://knoppix.net or a Ubuntu boot CD) and mount the `ext` and one of your `NTFS` partitions. The Linux NTFS-3G driver (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G) can be regarded as mature (but it seems it should not be used on partitions accessed by Windows 8). To be completely safe, you can use an external USB drive without any important data for transferring the files.

Comment: Yep, since I come from the MS-DOS side, it didn't occur to me to use a live-cd (mostly because they don't really exist in the MS world).  @mpy suggestion is best if you need the data.

Comment: @Blackbeagle Windows 8 does it now!